# Shape recognition (recognizes hand drawn basic shapes - rectangles, ellipses, triangles etc.)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I want to detect hand drawn basic shapes - rectangles, ellipses, triangles etc.

Does anybody have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: where do those shapes come from? An image file from the web? The camera? Or are they even drawn inside your app?

Comment: We have to draw shapes on view....( free hand drawing)..Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [An iPhone library for shape recognition via the camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093143/an-iphone-library-for-shape-recognition-via-the-camera)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the OpenCV library. Actually this library has the focus of computer vision, i.e. analyzing pixeldata of images and video and might be too heavy for your task. But on the other hand it is very powerfull and available on many plattforms (even on iOS). And a hand drawn image with shapes is also just a set of pixels, isn't it ;-)

You might have a look at the manual:

http://www.sciweavers.org/books/opencv-open-source-computer-vision-reference-manual

There is plenty of information about OpenCV here on stackoverflow as well. Some hints on stackoverflow are here:

[DETECT the Edge of a Document in iPhoneSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921256/detect-the-edge-of-a-document-in-iphonesdk)

and here

[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am looking for an application named iDesk.iDesk have Shape Recognizer concept So Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Actually i want to redraw the hand drawn shape with actual object at same points,say for instance Circle or Squere or rectangle..etc. If i will draw triangle with not closing end points program will detect Triangle as object and redraw with actual object.